# Logstash couchdb_changes doesn't correctly propagate document deletion to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, couchdb, logstash

I am trying to use the [couchdb_changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-couchdb_changes.html) Logstash plugin to detect my CouchDB changes and update Elasticsearch index adequately.

Document creations/updates work fine, but somehow deletions do not work.

Here is my Logstash configuration:

```
input {
  couchdb_changes {
    host => "localhost"
    db   => "products"
    sequence_path => ".couchdb_products_seq"
    type => "product"
    tags => ["product"]
    keep_revision => true
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "products"
    # Pass the CouchDB document ID to Elastic, otherwise it is lost and Elastic generates a new one
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
  # Debug
  stdout { 
    codec => rubydebug {
      metadata => true
    } 
  }
}
```

I came across [this link](https://www.hoekstra.nu/wordpress/blog/2015/08/12/logstash-couchdb-elasticsearch-bending-your-rivers/) but the "protocol" parameter no longer exists in the [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) Logstash plugin, and I would expect such a huge bug to be fixed by now.

In my Logstash console I see this when I delete a CouchDB document (from Futon):

```
{
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-05-13T14:06:55.734Z",
          "type" => "product",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "product"
    ],
     "@metadata" => {
           "_id" => "15d6f519d6827a2f28de4df1d40082d5",
        "action" => "delete",
           "seq" => 10020
    }
}
```

So instead of deleting document with id "15d6f519d6827a2f28de4df1d40082d5", it replaces its content. Here is the document "15d6f519d6827a2f28de4df1d40082d5" after the deletion, in Elasticsearch:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/products/product/15d6f519d6827a2f28de4df1d40082d5?pretty'
{
  "_index" : "products",
  "_type" : "product",
  "_id" : "15d6f519d6827a2f28de4df1d40082d5",
  "_version" : 3,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "@version" : "1",
    "@timestamp" : "2016-05-13T14:06:55.734Z",
    "type" : "product",
    "tags" : [ "product" ]
  }
}
```

Any idea of why the deletion doesn't work? Is this a bug of the couchdb_changes plugin? The elasticsearch plugin?

For information, here are my app versions:
Elasticsearch 2.3.2
Logstash 2.3.2
Apache CouchDB 1.6.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the problem.
I had to manually add this line in the logstash output.elasticsearch configuration:

```
action => "%{[@metadata][action]}"
```

in order to pass the "delete" from metadata to Elasticsearch.

Now there is another issue with upsert, but it's tracked in a [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/issues/239).

Edit: To bypass theupsert issue, I actually changed my configuration to this (mainly, add a field to store whether the action is a delete):

```
input {
  couchdb_changes {
    host => "localhost"
    db   => "products"
    sequence_path => ".couchdb_products_seq"
    type => "product"
    tags => ["product"]
    keep_revision => true
  }
}

filter {
  if [@metadata][action] == "delete" {
      mutate {
        add_field => { "elastic_action" => "delete" }
      }
    } else {
      mutate {
        add_field => { "elastic_action" => "index" }
      }
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "products"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
    action => "%{elastic_action}"
  }
  # Debug
  stdout { 
    codec => rubydebug {
      metadata => true
    } 
  }
}
```

I am nowhere near an expert in Logstash/Elasticsearch, but this seems to work for the moment.